# Using training set / validation set for prediction after model assessment with test set?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction

When there is enough data, ML splits the data into 3 sets: **(1) training, (2) validation, and (3) test set.**

So in the training stage, an algorithm is trained in (1), "validate" the trained model's prediction accuracy with (2). (2) determines whether the model should be learned more with (1) or not.

After the training is over, the model's predictive accuracy is measured in (3). This is required as (3) is chosen independently (or assumed to be) from (1) and (2) and was not used in the training stage, so it provides "correct out-of-sample" result.

***My question is this:
After (3), i.e. after the model assessment is made, can I use (1) or (2) for predictions (i.e. the whole sample), for some next-stage purposes?***

My ultimate goal is to use predictions to make some other decisions. Let's say that I want to know which teacher the government should hire in order to maximize the students' potentials.

I start from choosing the "right" predictors, and end up with well-trained model that my predictors can actually predict well enough ("well enough" determined via (3)).

However, if I use only test set data for the next stage decision (i.e. which teacher to hire), it's equivalent to predicting for only 20% of the whole sample; 80% of teacher candidates wouldn't even get a chance to be hired.
(20%: test set fraction, 80%: training+validation set fraction)

So, after the learning is done, shouldn't I make the prediction for the whole sample, including (1) and (2) as well, in order to determine which teacher is the best?

I am not trying to compare model A and B after predicting for the whole sample. Given the model, I just want to fully use the data that I have for the next-stage decisions.

Is above reasonable? I couldn't find any references reflecting situations close to above.

Any idea from you will be very much appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

---

After reading the comment, I realized I mixed the things up. (Sorry for the confusion.)

**The "decision" would be "Among the hired teachers, who are the ones that shouldn't have been hired?"**

Whether the given set of features actually predicts improvements in students abilities will be identified by the learned model - assuming that previous teachers' teaching ability assessments are not so precise. This would be the setting that decision making variable is not already contained in the data set.

Comment: What exactly are next-stage decisions here? New unseen teachers? Or are you interested in something like "this teacher should've been hired but was not" and "this teacher was hired but that was probably not the best decision"? Is the data you are actually interested in already in your dataset?

Comment: @crux26 Did you figure this out? I have the same question. There are data points in my training sample that I'd like to obtain a predicted value for and compare them to actuals.